# Android in-app billing: Error consuming sku android.test.purchased (response: 5:Developer Error)

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have sent a test purchase intent via standard helper:

```
String SKU = "android.test.purchased";
mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, SKU, 10001, mPurchaseFinishedListener);
```

The purchase was made successfully, but when I try to consume the purchased item using:

```
mHelper.consumeAsync(inv.getPurchase(SKU), mConsumeFinishedListener);
```

I get the following error:

```
Error while consuming: IabResult: Error consuming sku android.test.purchased (response: 5:Developer Error)
```

- I've created a Play Store signed apk and uploaded to the Developer Console
- I've setup a test item in the Dev Console
- I've implemented onActivityResult

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the same error since 2013/03/08 til now. Before 03/08, consuming android.test.purchased works fine. I observe this product id, it seems to be cleared automatically with some period.

EDIT
An anonymous user added the following:

Here is the issue:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53077

Comment: Same here. I have tested in-app billing and worked fine, but a couple of days ago it started giving "developer error" each time when trying to consume an item. Purchasing works fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly publish the app on alpha or beta version of you google play store.

if you publish the app and the apk is only in "alpha testing" section then it is NOT availible to general public, only for activated testers in the alpha section.

EDIT: One additional note: "normal" uses will not find your app on Google Play, but also the activated tester can not find the application by using the search box.

Only the direct link to the application package will work. (only for the activated testers).
 https://play.google.com/apps/testing/yourpackagename